# rails 3 array undefine method

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, undefined

I have variable call items having array of items which contains following value

```
[[#<Item id: 16, item_name: "Titan limited edition watch", description: "This is watch", reference_no: 21541, price: 5000, currency_type: nil, payment_type: "0", created_at: "2012-02-29 06:53:38", updated_at: "2012-02-29 06:53:38", quntity: 500, avatar_file_size: 8805, avatar_file_name: "images.jpg", avatar_content_type: "image/jpeg", avatar_updated_at: "2012-02-29 06:53:38">], [#<Item id: 25, item_name: "Titan limited edition watch", description: "this is watch", reference_no: 2, price: 5000, currency_type: nil, payment_type: "0", created_at: "2012-03-02 13:06:39", updated_at: "2012-03-02 13:06:39", quntity: 5, avatar_file_size: 8805, avatar_file_name: "images.jpg", avatar_content_type: "image/jpeg", avatar_updated_at: "2012-03-02 13:06:39">]]
```

I try to make a loop like this

```
@items.each do |item|

end
```

and item variable contain following value

```
[#<Item id: 16, item_name: "Titan limited edition watch", description: "This is watch",     reference_no: 21541, price: 5000, currency_type: nil, payment_type: "0", created_at: "2012-    02-29 06:53:38", updated_at: "2012-02-29 06:53:38", quntity: 500, avatar_file_size: 8805, avatar_file_name: "images.jpg", avatar_content_type: "image/jpeg", avatar_updated_at: "2012-02-29 06:53:38">]
```

but when i try following gives me error

```
@items.each do |item|    
  item.item_name    
end
```

error is

```
undefined method `item_name' for #<Array:0xb6c1dffc>
```

please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of arrays; inside the loop, `item` is an array, and an array doesn't have an `item_name` method. You need to get at the item inside the array.

```
@items.each do |item|
  item[0].item_name
end
```

You can also `flatten` the array to make it one-dimensional:

```
@items.flatten.each do |item|
  item.item_name
end
```